# Simple If condition not working correctly for shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have the code bellow which is supposed to check if the 1st argument is anything other than "boot" or "shutdown"

```
if [[ "$1" != "boot" || "$1" != "shutdown" ]]
then
    echo "foo"
    exit 1
fi
```

the code looks correct but when I pass it boot, as in $1 = boot, it think that $1 is not equal to boot and print out "foo".

I am very confused and any help is appreciated.

Comment: That condition is always true.

Comment: If the first argument is `boot`, then it is not `shutdown`.  Perhaps you means to use `&&`.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but a pet-peeve of mine.  If your script is going to exit non-zero, it should emit an error message.  Error messages belong on stderr.  `echo "foo" >&2`

Comment: ...not just error messages; _all_ diagnostic information for the user belongs on stderr. So error messages, but also logs and prompts -- anything that isn't output as such. Otherwise that information will end up getting mixed into output redirected through pipelines / into files / etc., and not actually displayed.

Comment: oh I think I need more sleep, I see my error now haha